# How to become an CIVICRM AMBASSADOR

Tags: community

i hope you are well. i just want to know how to become an ambassador of civicrm in my countr

Best regards

Comment: Welcome to SE!  That's a phrase that has been used in various ways,  Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: if i have skills on integration of civicrm on drupal 8, how can i become a civicrm embassy in my country. by the way i am already ambassador of cms drupal here in my country.

Comment: I think the 'ambassador' concept with civicrm was more for organisation who are using civicrm and who would be happy to talk with other organisations who are exploring civicrm as a solution

Comment: if you want to 'get known' as a provider with skills in this area then you could a/ build up your reputation here on SE by answering questions, b/ be similarly helpful in Chat, c/ become a partner, d/ help with things like documentation, bug fixing etc etc. Not sure that is the sort of answer you were looking for but hope it gives you some ideas.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

There is this blog post describing it: https://civicrm.org/blog/josh/community-ambassadors-needed

I would go to https://chat.civicrm.org and in the Community channel post a message to Josh.